# What is wrong with this Trigger? Why does acc.Advisor__c not 'exist'? There is an Account Class in a Managed Package

Tags: trigger

```
trigger ATMTrigger on AccountTeamMember (after insert) {
    for (AccountTeamMember atm : Trigger.new) {
        List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, 
                                    Name, 
                                    Advisor__c 
                            FROM    Account 
                            WHERE   Id = :atm.AccountId];
        acc.Advisor__c = atm.UserID;  //ERROR 'Variable does not exist: Advisor__c '
        Update acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`acc` is a `List`, not a single `sObject`. You should also [bulkify your code](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices). Also, you don't need to query the records, since you already know their Id values.

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(AccountTeamMember atm: Trigger.new) {
  accounts.put(atm.AccountId, new Account(Id=atm.AccountId, Advisor__c=atm.userId));
}
update accounts.values();
```

The Map prevents us from updating the same account multiple times in the same transaction.

If the field has a namespace, you might need to include that as well:

```
  accounts.put(atm.AccountId, new Account(Id=atm.AccountId, pkgns__Advisor__c=atm.userId));
```